# Using VB.net DLL file on Android and iphone

Tags: android, iphone, vb.net, dll

I am having VB.net dll files which I need to use in Android and iPhone application.
Creating web service doesn't satisfy my requirement as I need to use this in offline mode.

Can please anyone suggest me how can I use this in Android or iPhone application development.
And whether is it really possible to do it?

Comment: Ugh why would you even want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try converting the app to C# (with automated tools) and use this:
http://android.xamarin.com/

Comment: If you just have the Dlls (and no sourcecode but you have the licence to do it), you could try decompiling the Dll to get the source.  And then recreate the Dlls in c# using the link above

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to use VB.Net dlls as it. If you have source code with you, you might try to convert it using some utility.